# Convert integer to an array (INCLUDING LEADING ZEROS) without using strings at all

Tags: c++

I am creating the game bulls and cows as an assignment for my C++ class. I have created the code to store an inputted integer into an array, however I have no idea how to store leading zeros which is a test case in the assignment. I am NOT allowed to use strings at all in this assignment.

For example, if the generated code is 0242, and the user enters 0242
the array that i get is {2, 4, 2}

This assignment would be stupid easy if we were allowed to use strings however, we are not allowed to use anything in the string library.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  //Get a guess from the user and store it in an array
  cout << "Enter a " << num_digits << " digit code: ";
  cin >> int_guess;

  int guess_digits[5];
  int new_guess[5];
  int i = 0;
  while (int_guess > 0)
  {
      guess_digits[i] = int_guess % 10;
      int_guess /= 10;
      i++;
  }
  for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
  {
      new_guess[j] = guess_digits[j];
      cout << new_guess[j];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I see a couple issues. (1) There's a dozen lines of code irrelevant to your question (the switch statement, for instance). Please construct a [mcve]. (2) Your code needs formatting.

Comment: I can remove the extra code, however, the array is being reversed first and then reversed again, this is how we learned it in class, if there is an easier way to store the entire integer in the array please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users **type characters**, **not integers**.

That's why, code like this:

```
int int_guess;
cin >> int_guess;
```

Is typically problematic as soon as the user types something that isn't an integer.

While you may not be able to use the string library, you can easily convert characters to numbers yourself.  By converting numbers to integer with the formula:

```
   char c;
   cin >> c;
   int x = c - '0';
```

The result is that "x" is the numeral value of the character typed.

Your input loop could look something like this.

```
char c;
int guess_digits[5];
int index = 0;

while (index < num_digits)
{
    std::cin >> c;

    if (!std::cin)
    {
        break;
    }

    // convert character to integer manually

    if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))
    {
        guess_digits[index] = c - '0';
        index++;
    }
    else
    {
        // invalid input - show an error
    }
}
```

The code example might be writing numbers to the guess_digits array backwards, but I'll leave that bug as an exercise for you to address.

Comment: what does the .eof() method do? and the backwards array is intended; later i store the forwards array using the backwards array with the for loop, but i guess this eliminates the need for that. Also thank you!

Comment: For the case in which a user delivers input from a redirected text file (e.g. `prog.exe < input.txt`)

Comment: You can take out the eof check if needed

Comment: @Zixxle - I tweaked the EOF detection to be a bit better.

Comment: Thank you, i made that change in my code too haha. This may be a stupid question but why does c - '0' work?

Comment: Let's take a character like `5`.  You understand it to be the number **5**, but it's **still a character** with an ASCII value of 53.  (Google for "ascii table" to see what I mean).  The digit characters, `0` - `9` are sequentially ordered in the ASCII table.  So `0` has an ASCII value of 48.  Hence `53-48` equals **5**.  Also, the "char" type in C is still an integer.  Typically, it's just a 1-byte integer. It's no different than short, int, or long type - other than it's range of allowed values.

Comment: Ah, okay that makes perfect sense now i had no idea the - operator would substract ASCII values of char, thank you!

Comment: It might be better to use `cin.get()` instead of the `>>` operator.

Comment: I think the right analogy is that the minus operation in C still subtracts integer values as you've always understood it.  It's just that the compiler is going to replace the literal `'0'` with `48`. And the C runtime is simply reading 1-byte integers with the `cin >> c` expression.  Remember, `char` is not a character type per se. It's an integer type that just happens to be useful for storing characters.  Hence, `c - '0'` is still an expression for subtracting two integers.

Comment: You don't need the `break` if you have the loop condition `while ((std::cin >> c) && (index < num_digits))`